# Apache Apex App Logs

Tags: apache, logging, apex

Where does the logs of apache apex app appear using apache apex cli and hadoop?
Like in the example project in this link.

https://github.com/DataTorrent/examples/blob/master/tutorials/partition/src/main/java/com/example/myapexapp/TestPartition.java

Answer (score 1):

Apache Apex runs as a Yarn application.

Application's localized log directory will be found in ${yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs}/application_${appid}. Individual containers' log directories will be below this, in directories named container_{$contid}. Each container directory will contain the files stderr, stdin, and syslog generated by that container.

Note that it is a distributed app and you might need to go to the node where the containers are deployed.

Comment: Thank you, I'm able to see logs output in container logs

Comment: @SanthoshiG if it is solves your problem, please accept the answer.